# Spring Security user authentication not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement authentication using spring security.

I have am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong.

web.xml has a security filter:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml has the defined url intercepts and authentication manager:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout**" access="permitAll" />

        <!-- Incoming Product -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/incomingProduct**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

        <!-- Maintanence pages -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/depotUser**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/product**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/productOwner**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/storageTank**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('Administrator')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/" 
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.tms.securityServices.UserSecurityService" >
        <beans:property name="depotUserDao" ref="depotUserDao" />
    </beans:bean> 

</beans:beans>
```

UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService. As per the configuration in the spring-security.xml this should get called to authenticate login request and inject the user into the session. **(Please correct me if i am wrong!)**

```
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
{
    DepotUser user = depotUserDao.findByUserName(username);
    System.out.println("User : " + user);
    if (user == null)
    {
        System.out.println("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isActive(), true, true, true,
            getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DepotUser user)
{
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (DepotUserRole userProfile : user.getUserRole())
    {
        System.out.println("UserProfile : " + userProfile);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userProfile.getRole()));
    }

    System.out.print("authorities :" + authorities);
    return authorities;
}
```

login controller handling the request:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/loginRequest" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginRequest(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            DepotUser user = depotUserManager.getUserByUsernamePassword(username, password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                request.setAttribute("firstName", user.getFirstName());
                request.setAttribute("lastName", user.getLastName());
                request.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
                request.setAttribute("userRoles", user.getUserRole());
                return "homePage";
            }
```

What happens is when i login the user gets logged with anonymous User .

The authentication does not get triggered as i am not getting at the break points in UserSecurityService. Nor in the spring controller which is handling the request.

Can anyone help me out?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one detail that doesn't seem right

In the configuration, in the login section:

```
<form-login 
        login-page="/" 
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
```

by specifying `login-page="/"`, this means that the POST request with the form data to perform the authentication must be to the `"/"` url, but you attempt to handle the authentication at the `"/loginRequest"` in your controller.

In second place, handling authentication is not something you have to manage by yourself in a controller, spring security does it automatically for you, just POST the form, to the url specified in the configuration.

**Update**:

As for the login form, you should make sure of the following things:

- the **action url of the form** matches the `login-page` parameter in the config, which is `"/"` in this case
- the **name property of the input field for the username** should match `username-parameter` in the config `"username"` in your case
- the **name property of the input field for the password** should match the `password-parameter`in the config, `"password"` in your case.

You should also remove `modelAttribute="loginUser"`

Comment: Thanks @saljuama I tried as per you suggestion, changing the <form-login login-page="/loginRequest". Still same behavious.

Comment: The part in the controller is just for testing purpose.

Comment: yea that testing might be preventing spring security to do what is suposed to do :) . Also, what @JacekWcislo said in his answer, how does your login form look like? can you add that code to your question?

Comment: @k.s that's ok, but to what url are you POSTing your login form? is it `"/"`? show the code of your login form please.

Comment: @k.s updated my answer according to the new information you provided

Comment: i tried your suggestions. still i am getting the same 404 error. Do i have to map the `j_spring_security_check` this url some place.

Comment: do you get a 404 when you try to access the login page, or when you try to authenticate?, if its the first case, you don't have to map in a controller the POST, but you do still need to map the GET request and serve the login page in the first place. And i haven't mentioned `j_spring_security_check` once.

Comment: no i am getting the 404 error when i am trying to login. i am getting the same error when i use `j_spring_security_check ` or `loginRequest`.

Comment: that means that for some reason, the spring security filters aren't in place

Answer (score 0):

How does your login form look like? Do you have

(thymeleaf)

```
<form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
```

(jsp)

```
<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
```

one of these? Can you show your view?

Comment: my login form `<form id="loginForm" method="post" modelAttribute="loginUser" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginRequest">` as requested @saljuama @JacekWcislo

Comment: can you elaborate on what is j_spring_security_check?

Comment: This is wrong; you're not triggering spring security filters. Read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html . Change your action to correspond to my post and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

@JacekWcislo, @saljuama i have a `login-page="/"` because my default landing page is the login page. 
i am adding as an answer as i wanted to show updated code.

after reading through the suggestions and links provided i have updated my security xml as follows:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout**" access="permitAll" />

        <!-- Incoming Product -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/incomingProduct**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

        <!-- Maintanence pages -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/depotUser**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/product**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/productOwner**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/storageTank**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('Administrator')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/"
            default-target-url="/homePage"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?invalidLogin=Yes" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"  

            />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />

        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    </beans:bean> 

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.tms.securityServices.UserSecurityService" >
        <beans:property name="depotUserDao" ref="depotUserDao" />
    </beans:bean> 

</beans:beans>
```

any my login jsp is

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" modelAttribute="loginUser" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
```

its giving me a 404 error. I assume i will have to map the spring security url .

i have it in my

> authenticationEntryPoint

is there anywhere else i'll have to map it?

Comment: in the future, instead of adding a new answer, it is better to edit your original post and include there the new information, it makes it easier to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding proper filters, entry point, and handlers.

code :

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <!-- Dashboard & resources -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginRequest**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/resources**" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- Incoming Product -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/incomingProduct**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

    <!-- Maintanence pages -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/depotUser**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/product**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/productOwner**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/storageTank**" access="hasRole('Administrator') and hasRole('Local_Administrator') and hasRole('Supervisor') and hasRole('Manager')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('Administrator')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/"
        login-processing-url="/loginRequest"
        default-target-url="/dashboard/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginPage?invalidLogin=Yes" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"  
        />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />

    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/loginRequest"/>
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/dashboard/home" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Spring security, if you want use method = RequestMethod.POST, you must disable csrf `<csrf disabled="true"/>`. Because data will be encoded.
Example:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    
    <form-login login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_login"
        default-target-url="/process-after-login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        logout-success-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```